# How to delete user from dbo.AspNetUsers table using sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I suppose this question may have been asked before, but I couldn't find an answer yet: from the Template Browser in SSMS I found the User -> Drop User procedure. The user name is Long Vilmerty 1. How to substitute the name in the procedure?

```
-- =====================
-- Drop User template
-- =====================

DROP USER <user_name, sysname, user_name>
GO
```

I've tried the most obvious combinations but it didn't work

Comment: Probably you need dynamic SQL

Comment: `Delete from dbo.AspNetUsers where UserName = 'Long Vilmerty 1'`  might need to delete some foreign keys if cascading deletes aren't used

Comment: @JamieD77 Ok, but is it possible to implement cascade delete ?

Comment: That will drop a database user not an AspNetUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing SQL users with row data in the AspNetUsers table.  The syntax you included is how you drop a database user from a database -- it has nothing to do with the AspNetUsers table.

To delete a user from AspNetUsers, you'll have to delete the user's info from any tables referencing that user, and then you can delete the user record from AspNetUsers.  Refer to http://blogs.visigo.com/chriscoulson/bulk-delete-asp-net-membership-users/ for details.